# Unable toRequired and disabled field

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, required, disable

I have a problem with my code , the required and disabled are not working for me .
I want that the " More informations" dependent on the status .

1. If the status is "Pending" or "In progress", the " More informations" field must not be open for entry (disabled )
2. if the status is  "Closed" , the " More informations" field becomes enabled an required .

==> Apex Class

```
public with sharing class Action {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Action__c getAction(Id ActionId){
        return [SELECT Id, Status__c, Information__c, Description__c  FROM Action__c 
         WHERE Id=:ActionId LIMIT 1];
    }    
}
```

==> JS

```
import getAction from '@salesforce/apex/Action.getAction';
import Status__c  from '@salesforce/schema/Action__c.Status__c';

export default class Acions extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {


 @track required = false;
   //hfs
   @track disableButton = false;

 connectedCallback() { 

        

        getAction({ActionId : this.recordId}).then(data=>
            {
                console.log('teste'+ data.Status__c);
                if(data.Status__c =='Closed') {
                   
                    this.disableButton = false ;
                    this.required = true ;
                 
                }
                  if(data.Status__c =='In progress' || Status__c == 'Pending') {
                    this.disableButton = true ;
                    this.required = false ;

                  }
                })

              }
```

==> HTML

```
      <tr>
                                <template if:true={getAction}>
                                  <td><lightning-input-field  field-name="Information__c" disabled={disableButton} required="true" >  
                                  </lightning-input-field>
                                  </td>
                                </template>
                                <template if:false={getAction}>
                                  <td><lightning-input-field  field-name="Information__c" disabled={disableButton} required="">  
                                  </lightning-input-field>
                                  </td>
                                </template>
</tr>
```

---

I modified my code with using the onchange & event.target.value , but it also don't work for me .

==> JS

```
ClosureInformation(event) {

    const field = event.target.Status__c;

    if(field =='Closed') {             
        this.info= event.target.value
        console.log('teste closed status');
        this.required = true;
        this.disableButton = false;
    }

    if(field=='En cours' || field== 'Pending'){}
    this.info= event.target.value
    console.log('teste  status');
    this.required = false;
    this.disableButton = true;

  }
```

==> HTML

```
 <tr>
                                  <td><lightning-input-field  field-name="Information__c" 
                                    value={info} onchange={ClosureInformation}
                                    required={required} disabled={disableButton} >  
                                  </lightning-input-field>
                                  </td>
                                
                            </tr>
```

When I commit the error please .

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the recordId property:

```
@api recordId;
```

Also, `required=""` is the same as `required="true"`.

You can do this instead:

```
<td><lightning-input-field  
       field-name="Information__c" 
       disabled={disableButton} 
       required={required} >
```